# How do I get Linux commands and scripts to work on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting, cygwin

I recently installed Cygwin and some of the packages that come with it so I could run my scripts which I created in a Linux environment. Now I am trying some commands which I use in the Linux environment like the `iostat`, `free` and `ifconfig` but they won't work. So my questions are:

Why won't some commands work?
Where should my scripts reside? And should they have an extension of **.bat** or should I let them keep their extension **.sh**?

Thanks guys! I really hope you could help me with this one.

Comment: Most likely ifconfig is not in your path. Are you logged in root?

Comment: Yes, I am. I guess some commands will not really work on Cygwin. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin doesn't have all the same commands as regular Linux. It's about as good an approximation as you're going to get on Windows though. To get better replication I had to make tons of aliases and functions just to get it to my liking, but even that still falls short.

As far as the shell scripts, I would leave the original extension. And open it with Cygwin but like I mentioned before, since not all commands are supported, your script might not be supported either.

Comment: I tried running the scripts, I placed it in my bin folder but some lines really wouldn't work. Thanks for answering.